# Changing url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change URL displayed in browser depend of folder

www.domain.com/site1
www.domain.com/site2

I need to show
www.domain.com/site1  -> www.aaa.com
www.domain.com/site2  -> www.bbb.com

How it's possible to do that?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com/site1

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aaa.com$1 [L]
```